# Find out whether jQuery validation was initiated via element() or form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

Within my custom highlight function for the jQuery validation plugin, I want to do different stuff, depending on whether the validation was initiated by a `blur()` of the invalid element (via `$('form').validate().element($element)`), or whether the form was submitted. (The highlight function is called, when an element is invalid. If this occurs on the form submit, the latter is aborted.)

As far as I understand it, the method which is called "onsubmit" within the plugin just calls the `element()` method for each element of the form, no variables indicating where the call came from are passed on, and I didn't find any accessible variable, or method of the validator, which I could use from my highlight function, to find out what initiated the validation. I hope that I just overlooked something, so if anyone has a hint... :)

(Alternatively maybe there is some external way to tell, whether the form is in the process of being submitted? I cannot really use the blur as indicator, as both can occur simultaneously. I could probably set some variable with a second "onsubmit" event and unset it after half a second or so, but that seems a bit messy, to me...)

Edit: I put together a small example to illustrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/b7L6d9kn/ - Here, attempted submission and a blur of the input field both change its background-color to red. How would I get it to turn purple only after attempted submission, but still validate on blur?

Comment: Perhaps show the actual code, construct a demo, and explain more about what you're trying to achieve with this plugin.  I find it unlikely that you have a request that is not already discussed or solved somewhere within the 6600 questions about this plugin.

Comment: Added to the op: https://jsfiddle.net/b7L6d9kn/ - I searched quite a bit (though not looking through 6600 questions...^^), of course, maybe not well enough...

Comment: Okay... that's a good start.  However, please refer to the FAQ for this site regarding how to write questions.  When including code, show the actual code in the post, in addition to the jsFiddle, because we don't rely on the external link to always be active.

Comment: Looking at your jsFiddle:  The plugin evaluates each field as valid or invalid.   There is no option to have a third state.  Like I asked before, if we knew ***why*** you wanted to do this, we could possibly make alternative suggestions for achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

## You are going to have to interact with a server-side scripting language to get this functionality.

### I have chosen PHP for my answer because that is what I know best.

You can check whether the post method has been used on your server, you can even pass the name of the form, as to query whether a specefic element has made the request.

```
if (isset($_POST['name_attribute_of_form']))
{ 
...do some logic
}
```

Comment: there may be different and correct answers depending on what scripting language is used.

Comment: Thanks, but the validation module aborts the submission, when an error occurs. (As part of this, the highlight method is executed, to show to the user, which element caused the error.) So the server should never receive anything in this case. (Unless I understood something really wrong... I will clarify that in the op.)

Comment: where is the information going to if not the server?

Comment: The validation plugin performs a client side validation of input fields e.g., and is called as an onsubmit event (among others). In the case of an invalid field it cancels the actual submission.